# OpenXML - Get add-in manifests on PPT

Tags: powerpoint, openxml-sdk, office-2016, office-web-app

I have an application and it have two manifest file. 
First manifest create a taskpane to office of right side.
Second manifest is a content add-in.

When i run the application it open an empty ppt file and show panes. (one on right side, one on the sheet). I save excel and i extract it as zip file and i see my webextensions files (xml) in webextensions directory.

[image]

webextesion1.xml -> taskpane (right side on ppt)

webextension2.xml and webextension3.xml -> two content pane on first presentation page.

When i open this file with OpenXML (PresentationDocument) i try to reach this file, but WebExtensionParts property shows one file (webextension1.xml -> taskpane).

Question: How and where can i reach content pane add-ins (webextension2-3.xml) with OpenXML?

My code:

[image]

I know that content pane is part of a slide, but how can i reach it?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I Find it in

```
ppt.PresentationPart.SlideParts where SlideParts (array) has WebExtensionParts property.
```

If you are looking for contentpane add-ins, you should search in

```
ppt.PresentationPart.SlideParts
```

beacuse of add-ins is part of slides, however task pane add-ins is in

```
ppt.WebExTaskpanesPart.WebExensionParts
```